# Is heat transfer = potential energy in formula of 1st law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

According to my textbook ,

1st law of thermodynamics is

Change in internal energy of ideal gas = K.E + P.E = Work done = $F_{ext}$ * displacement$_{walls}$

= n * degree of freedom * R * $\delta$T / 2 + 0.

Change in internal energy for any gas = W$_{macroscopic}$ + W$_microscopic$ or Thermal. W= work done here

= W + q

= $\frac{n * degree of freedom * R *$ \delta$ T_{diff}}{ 2}$ = P$_{ext}$($V_i$ - $V_f$) \delta$ is macroscopic work + q is microscopic work(No formula )

My Questions :

1. Here , if we are finding change in internal energy , why do we write macroscopic + micro work. Both should be microscopic right.
2. So , $\delta$ E for ideal gas was = $\frac{n * degree of freedom * R *$ \delta$ T_{diff}}{ 2}$ and so is same for the 1st law. Shouldn’t we have had added + P.E ?
3. Can we say this formula of 1st law on external + internal system because of the formula of work done ?.

Comment: Where did you encounter these phrases "macroscopic work" and "microscopic work"?  The usual classifications of energy-during-transfer are "work" and "heat".

Comment: @DanielHatton From an  online lecture sir.

Comment: @DanielHatton For microscopic work , it states it as thermal work. And macroscopic is work done or W

Answer (score 1):

When energy is being *transferred*, it can be classified as "work" or "heat" (it looks like this textbook/online lecture is using the name "macroscopic work" for what's usually called "work", and the name "microscopic work" for what's usually called "heat").  When energy is being *stored*, it can be classified as "(bulk) kinetic energy", "(bulk) potential energy", or "internal energy".  Energy can be transferred in a "macroscopic" way (work), but still end up stored in a "microscopic" way (internal energy) when it reaches its destination and vice versa.